# Using modulus operator in a python conditional statement

Tags: python, modulus

When i run the code, it gives me an error: not all arguments converted during string formatting

```
year = raw_input( "Please enter a year" )

if year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0:
    print ( "{0} is a leap year", year )
elif year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0:
    print ( "{0} is a leap year", year )
else:
    print ( "{0} is not a leap year", year )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `raw_input` returns a string, the line

```
year % 4
```

Is trying to perform a [string format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) operation, which shares the same operator `%` as modulus.

You need to convert your input to an integer, with `int()`.

Also, as [thefourtheye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1903116/thefourtheye) mentioned, the [boolean AND operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) is `and`, not `&&` like C uses.

So:

```
while True:
    # Prompt the user until they give a valid integer.
    year = raw_input( "Please enter a year" )
    try:
        year = int(year)
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass

if (year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0):
    print "{0} is a leap year".format(year)
elif (year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 == 0) and (year % 400 == 0):
    print "{0} is a leap year".format(year)
else:
    print "{0} is not a leap year".format(year)
```

Note the correct string formatting, using `format()` as well.

Comment: @thefourtheye I don't think you needed to do that, but ok. Left reference to you in there.

Answer (score 3):

1. Result of `raw_input` is always a string, you need to explicitly convert them to the type you want

   ```
   year = int(raw_input( "Please enter a year" ))
   ```
2. In Python, conditional and operator is represented with `and` not `&&`.

   ```
   if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0:
   ...
   elif year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 == 0:
   ...
   ```
3. And, when you use `{0}` you should use `.format`, like this

   ```
   print ( "{0} is a leap year".format(year) )
   ...
   print ( "{0} is a leap year".format(year) )
   ...
   print ( "{0} is not a leap year".format(year) )
   ```

Comment: This is true, but has nothing to do with the error the OP is getting.

Comment: The error is occurring at `year % 4`, because `year` is a string, and not an integer.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I managed to give all the possible fixes. Do you think any of them is still wrong?

Comment: Nope, I believe you've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

The output from `raw_input` will be a string; when you use the `%` operator, and the first operand is a string, it does [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), not modulo. (as in `year % 4`, `year` is a string, because it's the output of `raw_input`).

In short, you want `year` to be a number. You need something like:

```
year = int(year)
```

Comment: `strip` is not needed, `int` will ignore the whitespaces at both ends of the strings.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
year = raw_input( "Please enter a year" )
```

to:

```
year = int(raw_input( "Please enter a year" ))
```

and replace every `&&` with `and`

```
year = int(raw_input( "Please enter a year" ))

if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0:
    print ( "{0} is a leap year", year )
elif year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 == 0:
    print ( "{0} is a leap year", year )
else:
    print ( "{0} is not a leap year", year )
```